# Is it possible to change the URL of the gist containing the CLA?

Tags: github, open-source

I use  [cla-assistant](https://github.com/cla-assistant/cla-assistant) as my GitHub Contributor License Agreement (CLA) management bot.

Is it possible to change  the URL of the gist containing the CLA? (without having to export the  list of users who signed the CLA, unlink the repository, relink the repository with a a new gist URL and import the user list)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible.

From one of the repository maintainers on https://github.com/cla-assistant/cla-assistant/issues/223:

> unfortunately not. It works only the (long) way you have described.